# If return response HTTP 204, What a correct header connection value?

Tags: http, http-headers

If application will return response HTTP 204 .
What a correct header connection value (close or keep-alive)?

Answer (score 0):

[204](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204) means there is no body to send back. You would still typically keep the connection open for subsequent requests so don’t have to close it this point.

Think of this scenario:
A web page has a “contact us” form which makes an XHR call rather than a POST. In that case you might send back a 204 to say the XHR call was successfully logged but you can keep the connection open so user can still browse the rest of the site without having to reestablish the connection.

If however your endpoint is for API calls only and no further requests will me made sending `connection: close` may make sense to save server resources.

Answer (score -1):

> The 204 (No Content) status code indicates that the server has
>      successfully fulfilled the request and that there is no additional
>      content to send in the response payload body.

So according to my understanding, as the server doesn't have anything else to send in the response, the header should be 'close'

Comment: Disagree - see my answer.

Comment: @BarryPollard Yeah your answer makes sense. So I guess this question doesn't have enough information for a direct answer, we will need to know the actual use case to give a direct answer.